# Download a base64 Image data and save into memory

Tags: python, bytesio

For few days now I am trying to find how the BytesIO is working with what I want to do.
So basically I want to download a pdf that its base64 encoded. After downloading it I want to save the file but not on the disk but in memory. And then I need to upload the path of that file to an API. Does anyone know how I could do that?

Until now this is what I have so far.

```
def string_io_save(document_string: str, attach_id: str, file_name: str, file_type: str):
    img_data = b64decode(document_string)
    path = attach_id
    out_stream = BytesIO()
    with open('imageToSave.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(img_data)
        bytesio = BytesIO(f.read())
    return bytesio
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file-like BytesIO like this: BytesIO(img_data)

Your function this way is much simpler:

```
def string_io_save(document_string: str):
   img_data = b64decode(document_string)
   return BytesIO(img_data)
```

now you can work with the return value of string_io_save as if it were a regular file (which is very useful for testing purposes):

```
fp = string_io_save("base64-encoded-sting....")
foo = fp.read()
fp.close()
```

Comment: When I try to open it with fitz library to check if the pdf its an image or text I get an error cause the result its not a path of the file. Do you know maybe whats the problem here?

Comment: From the fitz docs looks like calling fitz.Document(stream=img_data, filetype='application/pdf') should be enough. No need to mess with BytesIO